Upload files to records in Salesforce Mobile when offline
I got this LWC to allow users to "upload" files (using Salesforce Mobile) while offline. The uploaded files would sync after the device is back online. The goal is to allow users to edit records (using a briefcase) and attach photos (as evidence).
JS:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import uploadFile from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploadController.uploadFile';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class FileUploadOffline extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    file;
    fileName = '';
    isOffline = false;
    db;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Detectar si está offline al inicio
        this.isOffline = !navigator.onLine;

        // Detectar cambios nativos del navegador (online/offline)
        window.addEventListener('online', this.handleOnline.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener('offline', this.handleOffline.bind(this));

        // Detectar cambios específicos de Salesforce Mobile (force:online/force:offline)
        document.addEventListener('force:offline', this.handleOffline.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('force:online', this.handleOnline.bind(this));

        // Inicializar la base de datos para almacenamiento offline
        this.initIndexedDB();
    }

    handleOffline() {
        this.isOffline = true;
        this.showNotification('Offline', 'Estás offline. Los archivos se subirán cuando vuelva la conexión.', 'warning');
        console.log('Modo Offline detectado');
    }

    handleOnline() {
        this.isOffline = false;
        this.showNotification('Online', 'Has vuelto a estar en línea. Intentando subir archivos pendientes.', 'info');
        console.log('Modo Online detectado');
        this.uploadStoredFiles(); // Intentar sincronizar cuando vuelva a estar en línea
    }

    handleFileChange(event) {
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
        this.fileName = this.file.name;
    }

    handleUpload() {
        if (this.isOffline) {
            this.storeFileOffline();
        } else {
            this.uploadFileToServer();
        }
    }

        storeFileOffline() {
                const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readwrite");
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");
                const fileRecord = { recordId: this.recordId, file: this.file, fileName: this.fileName };

                const request = objectStore.add(fileRecord);

                request.onsuccess = () => {
                        this.showNotification('Archivo almacenado', 'El archivo se almacenó localmente y se subirá cuando vuelva la conexión.', 'info');
                };

                request.onerror = (event) => {
                        console.error('Error en IndexedDB:', event.target.error);
                        this.showNotification('Error', 'No se pudo almacenar el archivo localmente: ' + event.target.error.message, 'error');
                };
        }

    uploadStoredFiles() {
        const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readonly");
        const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");

        const request = objectStore.getAll();

        request.onsuccess = async (event) => {
            const storedFiles = event.target.result;

            if (storedFiles.length > 0) {
                for (let storedFile of storedFiles) {
                    this.file = storedFile.file;
                    this.fileName = storedFile.fileName;
                    await this.uploadFileToServer(storedFile.recordId);
                }

                // Limpiar la base de datos después de subir los archivos
                this.clearStoredFiles();
            }
        };

        request.onerror = () => {
            this.showNotification('Error', 'Hubo un error al recuperar los archivos almacenados.', 'error');
        };
    }

    uploadFileToServer(recordId = this.recordId) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const fileContents = reader.result.split(',')[1];
            uploadFile({ fileName: this.fileName, fileContents, recordId })
                .then(() => {
                    // Actualizar el registro después de la carga
                    getRecordNotifyChange([{ recordId }]);
                    this.showNotification('Éxito', 'Archivo subido exitosamente.', 'success');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.showNotification('Error', 'Error al subir el archivo.', 'error');
                });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }

    clearStoredFiles() {
        const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readwrite");
        const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");
        objectStore.clear();
    }

        initIndexedDB() {
                const request = indexedDB.open("fileUploadDB", 1);

                request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
                        const db = event.target.result;
                        // Verifica si el object store ya existe para evitar recrearlo
                        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('files')) {
                                db.createObjectStore("files", { keyPath: "fileName" });
                        }
                };

                request.onsuccess = (event) => {
                        this.db = event.target.result;
                };

                request.onerror = (event) => {
                        console.error('Error al inicializar IndexedDB:', event.target.error);
                        this.showNotification('Error', 'No se pudo inicializar la base de datos para almacenar archivos offline.', 'error');
                };
        }

    showNotification(title, message, variant) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title,
            message,
            variant,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        // Remover eventos al desconectar
        window.removeEventListener('online', this.handleOnline);
        window.removeEventListener('offline', this.handleOffline);
        document.removeEventListener('force:offline', this.handleOffline);
        document.removeEventListener('force:online', this.handleOnline);
    }
}

The HTML file provides mobile access to the LWC:
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <supportedFormFactors>
        <supportedFormFactor type="Small"/>
        <supportedFormFactor type="Large"/> <!-- MOBILE -->
    </supportedFormFactors>
</targetConfig>

This beautiful piece of code is not working tho, and I have no clue why (I'm new to LWC). I would really appreciate any good advice (or any different approach).
EDIT: after tweaking the briefcase settings, now it does the job, but it is uploading the photo taken four times. It's now a different kind of fail...
Thank you all.

After lots of changes, I managed to solve the problem. Here is a functional solution for saving files (camera photos, for instance) while Salesforce Mobile is offline, and uploads them as soon as the device is back online.
JS:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import uploadFile from '@salesforce/apex/FileUploadController.uploadFile';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class FileUploadOffline extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    file;
    fileName = '';
    isOffline = false;
    db;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.isOffline = !navigator.onLine;
        window.addEventListener('online', this.handleOnline.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener('offline', this.handleOffline.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('force:offline', this.handleOffline.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('force:online', this.handleOnline.bind(this));
        this.initIndexedDB();
    }

    handleOffline() {
        this.isOffline = true;
        this.showNotification('[Offline]', 'Estás offline. Los archivos se subirán cuando vuelva la conexión.', 'warning');
        console.log('Modo Offline detectado');
    }

    handleOnline() {
                if (!this.isOffline) return; // Evitar que se ejecute más de una vez
                this.isOffline = false;
                this.showNotification('[Online]', 'Has vuelto a estar en línea. Se cargarán archivos, si están pendientes de subir.', 'info');
                console.log('Modo Online detectado');
                this.uploadStoredFiles();
    }

    handleFileChange(event) {
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
        this.fileName = this.file.name;
    }

    handleUpload() {
        if (this.isOffline) {
            this.storeFileOffline();
        } else {
            this.uploadFileToServer();
        }
    }

        storeFileOffline() {
                const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readwrite");
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");

                if (this.file && this.fileName) {  // Verifica que existan 'file' y 'fileName'
                        const fileRecord = { 
                                recordId: this.recordId, 
                                file: this.file, 
                                fileName: this.fileName, 
                                isUploaded: false // Agregar campo isUploaded aquí
                        };

                        const request = objectStore.add(fileRecord);

                        request.onsuccess = () => {
                                this.showNotification('[Archivo almacenado]', 'El archivo se almacenó localmente y se subirá cuando vuelva la conexión.', 'info');
                        };

                        request.onerror = (event) => {
                                console.error('Error en IndexedDB:', event.target.error);
                                this.showNotification('[Error]', 'No se pudo almacenar el archivo localmente: ' + event.target.error.message, 'error');
                        };
                } else {
                        this.showNotification('[Error]', 'Archivo o nombre de archivo no válido.', 'error');
                }
        }

        uploadStoredFiles() {
                const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readonly");
                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");

                const request = objectStore.getAll();

                request.onsuccess = async (event) => {
                        const storedFiles = event.target.result;

                        if (storedFiles && storedFiles.length > 0) {
                                for (let storedFile of storedFiles) {
                                        if (storedFile && storedFile.isUploaded === false) { // Verifica que el archivo esté definido y tenga isUploaded
                                                this.file = storedFile.file;
                                                this.fileName = storedFile.fileName;

                                                // Intenta subir el archivo
                                                await this.uploadFileToServer(storedFile.recordId);

                                                // Actualiza la propiedad isUploaded
                                                storedFile.isUploaded = true;
                                                const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readwrite");
                                                const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");
                                                objectStore.put(storedFile);  // Actualiza el registro en IndexedDB
                                        }
                                }
                        } else {
                                this.showNotification('[Info]', 'No hay archivos pendientes de subir.', 'info');
                        }
                };

                request.onerror = () => {
                        this.showNotification('[Error]', 'Hubo un error al recuperar los archivos almacenados.', 'error');
                };
        }

    uploadFileToServer(recordId = this.recordId, fileName = this.fileName) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const fileContents = reader.result.split(',')[1];
            uploadFile({ fileName, fileContents, recordId })
                .then(() => {
                    getRecordNotifyChange([{ recordId }]);
                    this.updateFileAsUploaded(fileName); // Actualizar el archivo como subido en IndexedDB
                    this.showNotification('[Éxito]', 'Archivo subido exitosamente.', 'success');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.showNotification('[Error]', 'Error al subir el archivo.', 'error');
                });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }

    updateFileAsUploaded(fileName) {
        const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readwrite");
        const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");

        const request = objectStore.get(fileName);

        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
            const fileRecord = event.target.result;
            fileRecord.isUploaded = true; // Actualizar el estado
            const updateRequest = objectStore.put(fileRecord); // Guardar de nuevo

            updateRequest.onerror = (e) => {
                console.error('Error al actualizar el archivo en IndexedDB:', e.target.error);
            };
        };

        request.onerror = (e) => {
            console.error('Error al obtener el archivo en IndexedDB:', e.target.error);
        };
    }

    clearStoredFiles() {
        const transaction = this.db.transaction(["files"], "readwrite");
        const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");
        objectStore.clear();
    }

    initIndexedDB() {
        const request = indexedDB.open("fileUploadDB", 1);

        request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
            const db = event.target.result;
            if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('files')) {
                db.createObjectStore("files", { keyPath: "fileName" });
            }
        };

        request.onsuccess = (event) => {
            this.db = event.target.result;
        };

        request.onerror = (event) => {
            console.error('Error al inicializar IndexedDB:', event.target.error);
            this.showNotification('[Error]', 'No se pudo inicializar la base de datos para almacenar archivos offline.', 'error');
        };
    }

    showNotification(title, message, variant) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title,
            message,
            variant,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

        disconnectedCallback() {
                window.removeEventListener('online', this.handleOnline);
                window.removeEventListener('offline', this.handleOffline);
                document.removeEventListener('force:offline', this.handleOffline);
                document.removeEventListener('force:online', this.handleOnline);
        }
}

Here is the Apex class:
public with sharing class FileUploadController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void uploadFile(String fileName, String fileContents, Id recordId) {
        Blob fileBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileContents);
        
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
        contentVersion.Title = fileName;
        contentVersion.PathOnClient = '/' + fileName;
        contentVersion.VersionData = fileBlob;
        contentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId = recordId;
        insert contentVersion;
    }
}

It is supposed to attach any file (from device or photo) to any object (I had to check the briefcase configuration as well).
Hope it helps for anyone trying to do the same.
Best
